# SQL WHERE clause runs with AND but not with OR

Tags: sql, apache-drill

I have below SQL query that filters out records based on a date field in WHERE clause. I have two different date attributes.

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE DATE1 >= '2002-01-01' OR DATE2 >= '2002-01-01';
```

This SQL gives a data read error. But when I replace the `OR` with `AND` it works fine.

How do I filter records to pick any record that has a either of dates greater than some arbitrary date?

EDIT1

I feel my questions was quite incomplete. I am using apache drill query engine. Plus the actual query is a join on two tables with the 2 date columns residing in the two different joined tables as below

```
   SELECT
        A.id AS my_id,
        B.is_active is_active,
        C.other_id AS id2
    FROM
        A
        INNER JOIN B ON A.id = B.id
        INNER JOIN C ON C.id = A.id
    WHERE
        A.date >= '2002-01-01' OR
        B.date >= '2002-01-01';
```

EDIT2

Below is my error message

```
SQL Error: DATA_READ ERROR: The JDBC storage plugin failed while trying setup the SQL query.
```

Comment: Do you have both date1 and date2 columns in your table?

Comment: You should probably use date literals. `'2002-01-01'` is a string while `DATE '2002-01-01'` is a date. This can be different in your DBMS, though, or may just not matter. What DBMS are you using?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name edited my question

Comment: @ThorstenKettner done

Comment: moreover these are postgresql tables

Comment: Add brackets to where condition (A.date >= '2002-01-01' OR B.date >= '2002-01-01')

Comment: I just found this: https://community.dremio.com/t/error-data-read-error-the-jdbc-storage-plugin-failed-while-trying-setup-the-sql-query/5042. It seems that there are products that just don't support apache drill as a jdbc source and can thus fail here and there. Don't know if this applies here.

Answer (score 1):

Well I tried a few things as suggested like converting the data type and using proper date literals none of that worked. But if I remove the 3rd table completely from the query, it works. Not sure why it does that but I can always join on the third table after creating a temp table, so I think that solves my problem. Basically the query that worked is below:

```
    SELECT
        A.id AS my_id,
        B.is_active is_active
    FROM
        A
        INNER JOIN B ON A.id = B.id
    WHERE
        A.date >= '2002-01-01' OR
        B.date >= '2002-01-01';
```

Comment: `AND` selects less rows than `OR`. Maybe some of those additional rows lie in a sector on disc that is not readable for some reason. By removing the table from the query, you may have removed exactly those rows that have this issue. (If this is true, then the error message is strange, though. Rather than reporting a parse error - this is how I interpret this message - the system should report a runtime error.)

Comment: yes, I didnt understood what that error msg means either. But thanks this is a good insight on whats happening here! @ThorstenKettner